# Change Entity Framework collation

Tags: entity-framework-6, collation

How can I change my Entity Framework 6 collation to support Arabic language?

I googled it a lot but I cannot find any good solution

Comment: Did you find anything about it??

Comment: No, not yet. I ran SQL commands from separate file

Comment: I did it same for every select i use 'collate' function but how to use 'collation' with update/insert statements??

Answer (score 0):

It is not EF issue, if you have default collation configured in your Sql database system then that will be picked by Sql. So collation is database system configuration thing. Probably you have to change your default collation on your machine.

Other option is to add after creating table statement in migration:

```
Sql('alter table <some_table> convert to character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci');
```